# The expected [App\Mail\WelcomeEmail] mailable was not sent. Failed asserting that false is true

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, phpunit

Where am i making a mistake ?  The blow code does not work for testing.
The user is found. There is not a problem like user null.

**The error message is:**

```
The expected [App\Mail\WelcomeEmail] mailable was not sent. Failed asserting that false is true.

   at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Testing/Fakes/MailFake.php:64
  60|         }
  61| 
  62|         PHPUnit::assertTrue(
  63|             $this->sent($mailable, $callback)->count() > 0,
> 64|             $message
  65|         );
  66|     }
  67|
```

**Test class**

```
class MailTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic feature test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testWelcomeMail()
    {
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
        Mail::fake();

        Mail::assertSent(WelcomeEmail::class);
    }
}
```

**Mail class**

```
class WelcomeEmail extends Mailable
{
 use Queueable, SerializesModels;

 public $data;

 public function __construct($data)
 {
    $this->data = $data;
 }

 public function build()
 {
    $user = User::find(3425);

    $address = 'myjourney@asdasd.com';
    $subject = __('email.welcome_to_journey');
    $name = __('email.my_journey');

    if ($user != NULL) {
        \App::setLocale($user->lang);
        $user->is_welcome_email_sent = 1;
        $user->save();

    }

    return $this->view('email.user_welcome', ['user' => $user])
        ->from($address, $name)
        // ->cc($address, $name)
        // ->bcc($address, $name)
        ->replyTo($address, $name)
        ->subject($subject);
 }
}
```

I can work other testing files like login, register etc but mailing didnt.

Comment: hello ... please do not put up pictures of code, code is text

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not sending the email along with the other credentials. Your function should look like that

```
public function testWelcomeMail()
{
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
    Mail::fake();
    Mail::to('<email_address>')->send(new WelcomeEmail(['user' => <some_number>]));
    Mail::assertSent(WelcomeEmail::class);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MAIL CLASS

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class WelcomeEmail  extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $data;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return [
            $this->to($this->data['emailTo']),
            $this->subject($this->data['subject']),
            $this->markdown('emails.forgotPassword', [
                'message' => $this->data['message'],
            ])
        ];
    }
}
```

TEST CASE

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;
use App\Mail\WelcomeEmail;
use Tests\TestCase;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;  
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class WelcomeTest extends TestCase
{
    use WithFaker;
   
    public function test_queued_email_testing(){
      
        Mail::fake();
        Mail::assertNothingSent();
        Mail::to($user->email)->send(new WelcomeEmail([
            'emailTo' => $user->email,
            'subject' =>'CHANGE YOUR PASSWORD',
            'message' => [
                      'email' => $user->email,
                      'token' => $user->remember_token,
                    ]
        ]));
        Mail::assertQueued(ForgotPassword::class);
    }


}
```

Laravel provide Mail fake feature for testing. You may use the Mail facade's fake method to prevent mail from being sent.

Answer (score -2):

Is there actually a User with id 3425?

```
$user = User::find(3425);
```

Your code might break here, since we cannot retrieve lang from a null object. This line should probably be removed as it already is used on a line further below where you check if the user exists.

```
\App::setLocale($user->lang);
```

It also seems like your email template uses data from the $user, since the user object is passed to the template. This may also break if you expect the user to exist.

Comment: The id belongs to actually user. Normally, the code is working in the project

Comment: Are you using the same database when doing the tests? Your test class is using the RefreshDatabase, which is clearing your database when testing. Unless I'm mistaken, there should be no user if you haven't added one at the start of the test.

Comment: yes, i am using the same database to test it. I have already another testing class to login with creadiantials and it works.